# Access Denied - LDAP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

i using ldap and trying to make scheme like this : 
I try login into " Web Application Dashboard ", using existing username in the database server (in this case using sql server)

[image]

this is Spring-security.xml code :

```
    <beans:beans>
    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="intra.anabatictech.com" />
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://10.8.8.11:389/" />
        <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="userDetailsService" /> 
    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.anabatic.alc.service.impl.ldap.LdapUserService" />
</beans:beans>
```

this is LdapUserService.ldap code:

```
package com.anabatic.alc.service.impl.ldap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import com.anabatic.alc.bean.UserDetailAlc;
import com.anabatic.alc.dao.admin.auth.UserDao;
import com.anabatic.alc.entity.admin.auth.User;
 import com.anabatic.alc.entity.admin.auth.RoleMapping;
 import com.anabatic.alc.enums.RolesEnum;

 @Service
 @Transactional(readOnly=true)
 public class LdapUserService implements UserDetailsService, GrantedAuthoritiesMapper{

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
private User user;
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    this.user = this.userDao.findByUsername(username).get(0);
    if(this.user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error tidak ada user");

    List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (RoleMapping rm : user.getRoleMapping()) {
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rm.getRole().getRole()));
    }

    UserDetailAlc userDetailAlc = new UserDetailAlc(username, 
            user.getPassword(), 
            true, 
            true, 
            true, 
            true, 
            roles);

    mapAuthorities(roles);

    return userDetailAlc;
}

public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

    Set<RolesEnum> enums = EnumSet.noneOf(RolesEnum.class);

    for(GrantedAuthority authority : authorities){
        if(RolesEnum.ROLE_ADMIN.equals(authority.getAuthority())){
            enums.add(RolesEnum.ROLE_ADMIN);    System.out.println("admin");
        }else if(RolesEnum.ROLE_USER.equals(authority.getAuthority())){
            enums.add(RolesEnum.ROLE_USER);     System.out.println("user");
        }else if(RolesEnum.ROLE_SUPERVISOR.equals(authority.getAuthority())){
            enums.add(RolesEnum.ROLE_SUPERVISOR);   System.out.println("agent");
        }
    }
    return enums;
}
}
```

i'm trying to authentication using `LDAP` but i failed, 
this is the info from console when i run the program

```
INFO : org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Ignoring PartialResultException
```

result :

[image]

i think its success connect the authentication with the server, because when i login and insert username and password that same with the server is success but maybe can't get the details from the account i use

can you help me , what must i do so i can login succesfully? 
thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked that you can connect to the LDAP server? The port is correct ?

Comment: @KennethClark : i have checked it and connected, and port is correct too. . :(

Comment: Turn on `DEBUG` level logging there may be more information. This error is usually as simple as unable to connect or invalid credentials.